# How does one update arrays on Atlas using Mongoose and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

My Schema is as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const usersSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    fplEmail: String,
    role: { type: String, enum: ['ADMIN', 'USER'] },
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    team: [Number],
    userFollowing: [String],
    userFollowers: [String],
  },
  { collection: 'users' }
);

module.exports = usersSchema;
```

My model looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const usersSchema = require("./users-schema")
const usersModel = mongoose.model("UserModel", usersSchema)

module.exports = usersModel
```

A document in my collection looks like this:

```
{
    "team": [],
    "userFollowing": [],
    "userFollowers": [],
    "fplEmail": "hluzinho@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "Ndabe",
    "lastName": "Mahluza",
    "__v": 0
}
```

My query looks like this:

```
const saveUserTeam = (userEmail, userTeam) => {
  console.log('user email:', userEmail);
  console.log('user team:', userTeam);
  usersModel.updateOne(
    { fplEmail: userEmail },
    { $set: { team: userTeam } }
  );
};
```

These are the arguments going in, which I'm printing in the saveUserTeam function.

[image]

The query works fine when I do it via the mongo shell. And the mongoose find and create functions work fine. So I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: wrap your function in async function and put await before update query.

Comment: My friend, you are a life saver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [turivishal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8987128/turivishal), "wrap your function in async function and put await before update query."